# pyspark redueByKey modify single results

Tags: python, mapreduce, pyspark

I have a dataset that looks like this in pyspark:

```
samp = sc.parallelize([(1,'TAGA'), (1, 'TGGA'), (1, 'ATGA'), (1, 'GTGT'), (2, 'GTAT'), (2, 'ATGT'), (3, 'TAAT'), (4, 'TAGC')])
```

I have a function that I'm using to combine the strings:

```
   def combine_strings(x,y):
        if (isinstance(x,list) and isinstance(y, list)):
            z = x + y
            return z
        if (isinstance(x, list) and isinstance(y, str)):
            x.append(y)
            return x
        if (isinstance(x, str) and isinstance(y, list)):
            y.append(x)
            return y
        return [x,y]
```

The result I get is:

```
samp.reduceByKey(lambda x,y : combine_strings(x,y)).collect()
[(1, ['TAGA', 'TGGA', 'ATGA', 'GTGT']), (2, ['GTAT', 'ATGT']), (3, 'TAAT'), (4, 'TAGC')]
```

What I want is:

[(1, ['TAGA', 'TGGA', 'ATGA', 'GTGT']), (2, ['GTAT', 'ATGT']), (3, ['TAAT']), (4, ['TAGC'])]

Where everything is an array.  I can't tell if pyspark is calling combine_strings on a result where there's 1 entry or if I can tell reduceByKey to do something with singleton results?  How do I modify the reduceByKey() or the combine_strings function to produce what I'd like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could first map the values into lists and then only combine those lists:

```
samp.mapValues(lambda x : [x]).reduceByKey(lambda x,y : x + y).collect()
```

The problem here is that those singletons are not affected by `reduceByKey`. Here is another example:

```
samp = sc.parallelize([(1,1),(2,2),(2,2),(3,3)])
>>> samp.reduceByKey(lambda x, y : x + y + 1).collect()
[(3, 3), (1, 1), (2, 5)]
```

Comment: That works for this problem.  Thanks!  Do you know if there's a way to do the other part of the answer?  (ie: do something specific to singletons in reduceByKey)

Comment: There is no way to achieve the same with the reduceByKey, as  the method will not be called when there is just a unique key.